# How to disable ICMP redirect packets in Cisco IOS?

Tags: cisco, configuration, ios, icmp, interface

I'm studying a "good practices" document for Cisco IOS, and one of its controls tells me to disable ICMP Redirect packets in the router. Sounds reasonable. So I go test it in Cisco Packet Tracker (a nifty little network emulator program). In my virtual router's IOS CLI, I type the following:

```
jcios01#config term
Enter configuration commands, one per line.  End with CNTL/Z.
jcios01(config)#interface GigabitEthernet9/0
jcios01(config-if)#no ip mask-reply
                          ^
% Invalid input detected at '^' marker.
```

I'm puzzled. That's what the document told to do. enable, "config term", "interface " and then "no ip mask-reply". Am I forgetting something?

Yes, I'm a Cisco newbie.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On a real IOS, the command to disable icmp redirects is somewhat misleading as it's under the "ip" submenu, but the help clarifies the trouble :

```
router#conf t
Enter configuration commands, one per line.  End with CNTL/Z.
router(config)#int f1/0
router(config-if)#no ip ?
Interface IP configuration subcommands:
<snip>
  redirects           Enable sending ICMP Redirect messages

router(config-if)#no ip redirects 


router#sh run int f1/0  
!
interface FastEthernet1/0
 description --- WAN
 ip address dhcp
 no ip redirects   <<<
 no ip proxy-arp
 ip nat outside
 ip virtual-reassembly
 duplex auto
 speed auto
 no cdp enable
end
```

Here interface configuration is shown with some other useful options for an "insecure" interface.

Btw, PacketTracer is great to learn the IOS commandline, but I found its behavior way too much different from a true IOS to be useful.

You may take a look at dynamips/dynagen/gns3, or even quagga. Dynamips, and its frontend gns3 are used to realistic labs, as they use a real IOS image, and quagga is an IOS-like routing daemon for unixes.

Comment: Yeah, in the end it was PacketTracer's problem. Even the alternative syntax I tried first (no ip mask-reply) worked. I hooked up an old 2511 we had lying around and everything went just fine. Thanks!

Comment: This is good reading about redirects :) http://packetattack.org/2011/05/26/the-host-route-you-cant-delete-icmp-redirects-the-clear-ip-redirects-command/